# Can't set cookies with req.cookies

Tags: node.js, express

```
req.login = (user) => {
    const token = createJWTToken({ user });
    console.log(token);
    res.cookie('jwt', token, { 
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15, // would expire after 15 minutes
      httpOnly: true, // The cookie only accessible by the web server
    });
    req.user = user;
};
```

I use express, cookieParser is correctly used, but are never set.
Tried on other browser, and differents options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[req.cookies](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies) is an object and you can get cookie by using [req.cookies](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies) object and if you need to set cookie then use [res.cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) function(as you are doing in your code).

**Note:** Make sure `req` is a [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) object and `res` is a [Response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) object